# Audio plugin parameters at Matlab are always sliders?

Tags: matlab, audio, plugins

When creating an audio plugin with Matlab's audio toolbox (either when I use the examples given by mathworks), the plugin parameters I add to the interface, always appear as sliders when loading the .dll in my DAWs (tried at Reaper and Cubase). It happens with all the kinds of mappings.

This is how I create the parameters:

```
properties (Constant)
    PluginInterface = audioPluginInterface(...
        'PluginName','Headphones Converter',...
        'InputChannels',1,...
        'OutputChannels',1,...
        audioPluginParameter('cascos', ...
        'DisplayName','Modelo de cascos', ...
        'Mapping',{'enum','K44','Sennheiser','Otro'}));
end
```

This is how appears when testing it with `audioTestBench(Convolver)`:

[image: Plugin tried with Matlab]

After `validateAudioPlugin Convolver` and `generateAudioPlugin Convolver` this is how appears when I load the Convolver.dll file into the reaper. Instead a dropdown, a slider is drawn:

[image: Plugin opened in Reaper]

Why is not appearing a dropdown?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [mcve], then [edit] te post accordingly. Most pressing: what is your question? I see a bunch of code and a description of sliders, but nowhere a mention of a problem.

Comment: The problem is the first thing I wrote:  [When creating an audio plugin with Matlab (either when I use the examples given by mathworks), the plugin parameters I add to the interface, always appear as sliders when loading the .dll in my DAWs (tried at Reaper and Cubase)], the parameters are always sliders at the DAWs.  I have added two images to help.

Comment: But what is the problem? You described two different states of parameters appearing, but haven't mentioned which of the two is desired, nor where in the code the problem occurs. Also: since Stack Overflow is a **question** and answer site, it's helpful to ask a question. In English these are sentences which can receive an answer, and are marked with a question mark, ?, at the end.

Comment: The problem is that all the kind of plugin parameters of Matlab appear as sliders when putting the .dll in music programs. Does not matter if it is a dropdown or a checkbox, they always appear as sliders.  The first image is how Matlab says the plugin will be (and what I want), and the second what appears in the music program.  I uploaded all the code because I have no clue where the problem can be.

Comment: Have you read [the doc](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/audio/ref/audiopluginparameter.html) ???, there is a parameter `Style` which can be set to `dropdown`...

Comment: Tried, but sais 'Style' is not a recognized name. I am using 2019a, can be a 2019b feature??

Comment: does the example also result in a slider? `openExample('audio/EnumForEnumerationClassParameterMappingExample')`

Answer (score 1):

Starting in R2019b, you can set the `Style` property of `audioPluginParameter` to one of hslider, vslider, rotaryknob, checkbox, vrocker, vtoggle, and dropdown.

You can also replace the default graphics of the widgets with your own custom images using the `Filmstrip` property (the custom graphics can be seen only in a DAW, audioTestBench does not pick this up).

See this doc page for more information on customizing the plugin UI: https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/ug/plugin-gui-design.html